# Nested lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have the following code:

```
auto get_functor = [&](const bool check) {
    return  [&](const foo& sr)->std::string {
        if(check){
            return "some string";
        }
        return "another string"
    };
};
run(get_functor(true));
```

The `run` function signature:

```
void run(std::function<std::string(const foo&)> func);
```

I am getting the following error which is not so clear for me:

> ```
> error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'main::<lambda_6dfbb1b8dd2e41e1b6346f813f9f01b5>::()::<lambda_59843813fe4576d583c9b2877d7a35a7>' to 'std::string (__cdecl *)(const foo &)'
> ```

P.S. I am on MSVS 2013

**Edit:**

if I edit the code by replacing `auto` with the real type:

```
std::function<std::string(const foo&)> get_functor1 = [&](const bool check) {
    return  [&](const foo& sr)->std::string {
        if (check) {
            return "some string";
        }
        return "another string";
    };
};
run(get_functor1(true));
```

I am getting another error:

> ```
> error C2664: 'std::string std::_Func_class<_Ret,const foo &>::operator
> ()(const foo &) const' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'bool' to
> 'const foo &'
> ```

Which is totally messed up!

Comment: A side note: you should capture by value in the returned lambda: `return [=](const foo& sr) ...`. Since here you are getting a reference that will be outlived.

Then, what's the full code example that leads to that error?

Comment: Not reproducible http://ideone.com/gpz109

Comment: Works http://ideone.com/5ZZ7TQ

Comment: It appears from the error message that the function expects a raw function pointer, not an `std::function` object

Comment: @Rerito Some of them are non-copyable.. this is another problem to deal with now!

Comment: @Rerito see my edit please

Comment: the error message says you're passing a bool to a function that expects a foo ref

Comment: @RichardHodges Yes which is not logical at all

Comment: @HumamHelfawi try my MCVE, will post below.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi `get_functor` cannot be an `std::function<std::string(const foo&)>` because it intends to return something convertible to an `std::function<std::string(const foo&)`! See my answer.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi did it work?

Comment: @RichardHodges Yup!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the same error on VS 2013 with the following MVCE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

struct foo {};

std::string run(std::function<std::string(foo const&)> f) {
    return f(foo());
}

int main() {

    auto get_functor = [&](bool const check) {
        return [=](foo const&) -> std::string { // Line of the compiler error
            if (check) {
                return "CHECK!";
            }
            else {
                return "NOT CHECK!";
            }
        };
    };

    std::cout << run(std::function<std::string(foo const&)>(get_functor(true)));
    return 0;
}
```

I then get the error:

```
Error   1   error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'main::<lambda_1bc0a1ec72ce6dc00f36e05599609bf6>::()::<lambda_4e0981efe0d720bad902313b44329b79>' to 'std::string (__cdecl *)(const foo &)'
```

The problem lies with MSVC's inability to handle returned lambdas: when you do not specify the return type, it is trying to decay it into a regular function pointer. This fails because your lambda does capture elements!

Moreover, your fix is wrong since `std::function<std::string(foo const&)>` is not the type of `get_functor` but rather the type you want to return from it.

Forcing the embedding into an `std::function` of the returned lambda directly in `get_functor` will resolve your issue:

```
auto get_functor = [&](bool const check) -> std::function<std::string(foo const&)> {
    return [=](foo const&) -> std::string {
        if (check) {
            return "some string";
        } else {
            return "another string";
        }
    };
};
std::cout << run(get_functor(true));
```

Comment: I don't have a copy of MSVC2013 to hand to check (who does??) but would it help to add a trailing return type of decltype(auto)? converting to std::function seems like a bit of a heavyweight solution.

Comment: @RichardHodges That's a C++14 feature IIRC so it shouldn't work. Just in case, I tested what you suggested and it failed with error: `error C3553: decltype expects an expression not a type`. I am well aware that the type erasure behind an `std::function` comes with a price but the OP uses it just after with his `run` function. We're just doing it one step ahead here.

Comment: Ok, thanks for trying it. In that case I have proposed a functor-based version, which of course allows us to explicitly name the types.

Comment: @Rerito Stupid me! My fix is totally rubbish. Thank you very much it is working now :)

Answer (score 3):

Frankly, I sometimes wonder whether complex lambdas are worth the bother.

Breaking it down to a functor object of a known type will always work:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


struct foo
{
};

struct foo_functor{

    foo_functor(bool check) : check(check) {}

    std::string operator()(const foo&) const
    {
        if (check) {
            return "some string";
        }
        return "another string";
    }
    const bool check;
};

auto make_foo_functor(bool check) -> foo_functor
{
    return foo_functor { check };
}

void run(std::function<std::string(const foo&)> func)
{
    foo f;
    auto s = func(f);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

int main()
{

    std::cout << "c++ version: " << __cplusplus << std::endl;

    auto get_functor = [&](const bool check) -> foo_functor
    {
        return make_foo_functor(check);
    };

    run(get_functor(true));
}
```

Comment: Thanks it seems good solution since I am able to template foo_functor so the bool check will be compile time which I was searching for from the begining (typical X-Y problem :D )

Comment: That's more elegant and it can avoid the type erasure induced by `std::function`. I'ld say that's the way to go (compared to the 'hotfix' in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

From your edit, `get_functor1` is a lambda that takes a single `bool` argument and returns another lambda,
but you try to convert `get_functor1` to this function type:

```
std::function<std::string(const foo&)>
```

That is not compatible. Instead, if you want to avoid `auto` type deduction, you should use:

```
std::function<std::function<std::string(const foo&)>(bool)>
```

That is, a function that takes a bool and returns another function which takes a `const foo &` and returns a `std::string`

`get_functor1` then becomes:

```
std::function<std::function<std::string(const foo&)>(bool)> get_functor1 = [&](const bool check)
{
    return  [&](const foo& sr)->std::string {
        if (check) {
            return "some string";
        }
        return "another string";
    };
};
```